# apoc.do.case alternative for 5

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-apoc

In neo4j 4.^ versions, there is the a function apoc.do.case that allows you do to follow up query depending by case
As you can see here, https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/5/overview/, that function doesn't exist (yet?)
Is there any replacing function?

An use case:

```
CALL apoc.do.case([
  false,
  'MATCH (matched:Node {name:"random"})
  MERGE (a:Node{name:"A"})-[r:RELATION]-(matched) RETURN a AS node',
  true,
  'MATCH (matched:Node {name:"random2"})
  MERGE (b:Node{name:"B"})-[r:RELATION]-(matched) RETURN b AS node'
  ],
  'CREATE (c:Node{name:"C"}) RETURN c AS node',{})
YIELD value
RETURN value.node AS node;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of Neo4j 5.0, the APOC library is divided into two parts, Core and Extended. The function `apoc.do.case` is part of the APOC core.

[This is the link to it's documentation.](https://neo4j.com/docs/apoc/5/overview/apoc.do/apoc.do.case/)